# R - Converting Coordinates to Countries? (Large quantity)

Tags: r

I have a data set that includes meteorite landings. It is really cool to see, but it only has coordinates for location data: latitude, longitude, and another variable that includes both of those in a coordinate format.

Is there a way I can convert these into a new variable for the country in which they are located? I have heard of geonames, but that only does one at a time, and I am looking at over 30,000 locations (haha). I could also potentially use a function to go through it, but I've heard it will run into errors with points in the ocean, which there are some here.

**My goal here is to create a cartogram. If I can do that with the coordinates instead of making the country names for the entire world, please let me know.**

Any help with this is appreciated.

The data set can be downloaded at https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nasa/meteorite-landings, and the code can be filtered with this code:

```
meteor.original <- read_csv("meteorite-landings.csv")
meteor <- meteor.original %>%
  filter(year >= 860 & year <= 2016) %>%
  filter(reclong >= -180 & reclong <= 180 & (reclat != 0 | reclong != 0))
head(meteor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's possible to do this with several different online APIs, the free reverse geocoding APIs tend to handle only one point at a time, and a large data frame like yours could take hours to work through.

I would be tempted to use an R package with country info and map the points to countries using `sf` or `sp`.

The following function returns a vector of country names given a vector of latitudes and a vector of longitudes:

```r
get_countries <-  function(long, lat)
{ 
  points <- cbind(long, lat)
  countriesSP <- rworldmap::getMap(resolution = 'low')
  pointsSP = sp::SpatialPoints(points, sp::CRS(sp::proj4string(countriesSP)))  
  sp::over(pointsSP, countriesSP)$ADMIN
}
```

So your code could be something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

meteor.original <- read_csv("../meteorite-landings.csv")

# Get meteor counts per country
meteor <- meteor.original %>%
  filter(year >= 860 & year <= 2016) %>%
  filter(reclong >= -180 & reclong <= 180 & (reclat != 0 | reclong != 0)) %>%
  mutate(latitude = as.numeric(gsub("^\\((.*), .*$", "\\1", GeoLocation)),
         longitude = as.numeric(gsub("^.*, (.*)\\)$", "\\1", GeoLocation)),
         country = get_countries(longitude, latitude)) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  count()

# Get a world map, left join the meteor counts and plot
sf::st_as_sf(rworldmap::getMap(res = "li")) %>%
  rename(country = ADMIN.1) %>%
  left_join(meteor, by = "country") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = log(n)), colour = NA) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "black", 
                       breaks = log(c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 20000)),
                       labels = exp,
                       name = "Meteorite\nCount") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]